# data.frame into matrix (R) , rownames() error

Tags: r, csv, matrix, dataframe

I have a data.frame ("data.csv") of 93 x 28 I want to convert into matrix for further plotting, it looks like this:

```
SYMBOL  BT.20   CAL.51  MDA.MB.436  BT.549
A   3.039   4.908   3.865   3.818
B   4.349   5.399   6.071   5.313
C   7.509   8.091   6.48    6.660
D   3.429   4.394   3.622   3.873
E   3.369   6.716   3.557   3.346
```

the code

```
data <- read_csv("data.csv")
rnames <- data[,1]              # assign labels in column 1 to "rnames"  
mat_data <- data.matrix(data[,2:28])  # transform column 2 - end into a matrix
rownames(mat_data) <- rnames                  # assign row names
```

produces

```
ERROR: Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = list(SYMBOL = c("A", "B",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

column 1 doesn't have duplicate names or missing values

edit:
with  `read.csv()`  instead, it works just fine

Comment: You should debug your code. Add `print(rnames)`.

Comment: or you can post the result of `str(rnames)` and `str(mat_data)`.  Seems like a dimension problem

Comment: Have you tried `read.csv("data.csv", row.names = 1)`?  It assigns them in `read.csv`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, actually I was loading the data.frame using the "import dataset" feature of Rstudio, which is read_csv ,,, if I load it "manually" with read.csv() I dont get the error. I guess they deal differently with the header by default ?

Comment: They are two different functions. `read.csv` is the base R one.

Comment: @AitorMalaka See my comment under 42- 's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that the value being assigned to the rownames is a list and the "length" of a list with a single vector in it is 1, rather than the length of the vector. I'm not able to say why that should be happening since the usual behavior is for the "[" function to "drop" single columns into atomic vectors. Like you, I would have expected `rnames` to be an atomic vector of length 39, but it appears you need to use this instead:

```
rownames(mat_data) <- unlist( rnames )              # assign row names
```

Rich and Apom have better eyes than I do. The read_csv function is producing an object with a different class and associated extraction function than would have `read.csv`. Since you are in the "hadleyverse", you therefore should use this:

```
 rnames <- data[[1]]
```

The `tibble`-classed objects have a different version of the `[`-function than do data.frames. The `[[`-function appears to act the same for both classes.

Comment: Might be caused by the use of `tibble` or `dplyr` : `as_tibble(mtcars)[, 1]` is a tibble, not a vector. `tibble` "corrects" the `drop = TRUE` default behavior of `"["()`

Comment: If that's true then `unlist` would work but it could be made unnecessary by using `rnames <- data[[1]]` as the creation of `rnames`, since `"[["`does "drop" the dimensions.

Comment: "hadleyverse" = :-)